# 'estimatedTimeRemaining' is only available on iOS 11.0 or newer for Progress object

Tags: ios, swift, progress

I am working with `Progress` object from `Foundation` (link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/progress)

I am doing a firmware update to a peripheral in my iOS app. 
I need to have a clock going backwards to show estimated time remaining, so I wrote this code (I use rx for binding the timeRemaining value to my `UILabel`:

```
@objc func updateFirmwareProgress() {
    guard let progress = firmwareProgress else {return}
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        timeRemaining.value = progress.estimatedTimeRemaining ?? 0.0
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
}
```

To my surprise, this is only supported on iOS 11. Is there a way to workaround this and get the time remaining for earlier versions?

Comment: Is `timeRemaining.value` only available in iOS 11, or `progress.estimatedTimeRemaining`? What classes are they? Where do they come from?

Comment: progress.estimatedTimeRemaining in the docs is a TimerInterval. I will link to the docs in an edit so people can understand which object i am talking about

Comment: I see now. It looks like you'd need to calculate for yourself how much time is remaining. You'd need to calculate the speed of progress, and then show the remaining time as a function of how much progress remains divided by the speed.

Comment: I guess I just need to estimate it myself